# Show the reply to an ajax call in the javascript console

Tags: ember.js

I have the following application:

```
var MyApp = Ember.Application.createWithMixins({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    VERSION: window.APPVERSION ? window.APPVERSION : '',
    /**
      Specifies what HTML element inside index.html Ember
      should manage for you.
    **/
    rootElement: window.TESTING ? '#qunit-fixture' : '#myapp',
    /**
      Hook, is invoked from the framework as soon the app becomes ready to use.

      @method ready
    **/
    ready: function () {
        Ember.Logger.debug('DEBUG: MyApp.VERSION : ' + MyApp.VERSION);
        Ember.Logger.debug('DEBUG: -------------------------------');
    },
    /**
      Our own $.ajax method around jQuery's. Makes sure the .then method
      executes in an Ember runloop for performance reasons.

      @method ajax
    **/
    ajax: function() {
        var reply = $.ajax.apply(this, arguments);
        Ember.Logger.debug('ajax reply : ' + reply);
        return reply
    },

    ...
});
```

As you can see, I am trying to see on the console the content of the ajax reply. But I am unable to see this. How can I show in the javascript console the data returned by the server? I am already able to see this by inspecting the network communication (in chrome Developer tools, for example), but I would like to be able to show it also in the console (the reason being that, although the data returned is fine, ember is not rendering anything, so I need to investigate where this is going wrong, and I want to start with visualizing the reply that ember is getting)

Is the  `ajax` method not called at all? Why is it there then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about the `MyApp.Application.ajax`. This is not a standard ember method, so it is not used. The right approach is, as intuitivepixel suggested, to overload the `RESTAdapter.ajax` method:

```
MyApp.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        var ajax_reply = this._super(url, type, hash);
        console.log('ajax_reply (promise) -> '); console.log(ajax_reply);
        return ajax_reply;
    }
});

MyApp.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter:  MyApp.Adapter.create()
});
```

This still does not allow me to see the `json` reply (I am just able to see the promise, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109480/hook-into-the-then-method-of-a-promise) for a further discussion), but is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `ajax` method lives under your `MyApp` namespace you have to invoke it using `MyApp.ajax(...)` to have it actually called. You can also remove the extra `ajax` and use ember's ajax method directly instead (which is just a wrapper around jQuery's), try doing `$.ajax(...)`, this should work.

But if you want to use your own `ajax` wrapper you should call it this way:

```
MyApp.ajax(url, {
  data: {
    ...
  },
  type: 'POST' /* can be GET, PUT, POST etc... */
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I understand that by defining the `ajax` method in the application mixin, ember is automatically using it to perform any ajax request. I am doing `$.ajax` in the `ajax` method in the Mixin. But the `ajax` method  in the mixin is not being called at all. Why is that?

Comment: no ember is not automatically using it, this is because your `MyApp.ajax` is never called. you should call `MyApp.ajax` if you want it called at all, otherwise use the built-in `$.ajax`, but outside the `ajax` wrapper, like in app.ready for example...

Comment: the wrapper is usefull to have a single point where you can tweak things, but you have to use it for it to be called, I hope it makes sense

Comment: This is what I mean. `MyApp.ajax` (a.k.a. the `ajax` method in the mixin) is not being called by ember. What is the point of overloading the `ajax` method of ember if it is not being used? In my code there are no direct calls to `ajax`: this is done internally by ember. So the only place where I can overload the ember `ajax` method is during the Application definition (`Ember.Application.createWithMixins`) which is what I do. But ember does not use it. Why?

Comment: have a look here, the discourse.org is build with ember but without ember-data, they use also a custom wrapper, see here:https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse.js.

Comment: one last thing, the `ajax` method in the App namespace is not an overload, it actually an extra `ajax` which then uses the built-in method under the hood.

Comment: I see. Now the question is: how can I tell ember to use `MyApp.ajax` method then? If this can not be configured in the `Application`, where can this be configured?

Comment: lamentably this is not that easy to do without overriding core parts of ember (which is discouraged) but you could create your own RESTAdapter from which you then call your own ajax wrapper `MyApp.ajax`. If you don't want to use ember-data at all, you can have a look at this blog post where it is very well explained: http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html