# Hook into the .then method of a promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

(js newbie here)

I have overloaded the `RESTAdapter`:

```
/*
  The default RESTAdapter in the application.

  An instance of this object will be created automatically.
*/

MyApp.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        var ajax_reply = this._super(url, type, hash);
        console.log('ajax_reply (promise) -> '); console.log(ajax_reply);
        return ajax_reply;
    }
});
```

Now I get the `promise` which I can see in the console:

[image: promise]

I would like to hook into the `.then` method so that I can show the  `json` data returned by the ajax call, but without interferring in the workings of the `RESTAdapter`. For example, the `RESTAdapter.find` method is:

```
  find: function(store, type, id) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type), adapter = this;

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), "GET").
      then(function(json){
        adapter.didFindRecord(store, type, json, id);
    }).then(null, DS.rejectionHandler);
  },
```

I would like to see in the console all the json replies passed via the `.then` method. How can I "hook" into the promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
MyApp.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    var ajaxPromise = this._super(url, type, hash);
    ajaxPromise.then(function(json){
      console.log(json);
    });
    return ajaxPromise;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To log all `.ajax()` responses, do what @LukeMelia suggests.

To log the response to a particular `MyApp.Adapter.ajax()` call, try :

```
MyApp.Adapter.ajax(url, type, hash).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
}, function() {
    console.log('.ajax error');
});
```